# Primary key error when sending Push Notifications from PHP

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have developed a simple application that uses APNS. The app runs fine and receives notifications when i used my host for php but its not receiving Notifications when i send the php code with certificate to a person who is in another country. he then executes the apns php code on its side but the iPhone app does not receive any Notifications. Its giving error of primary key in php code.

I have followed this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution of my problem, its was the issue of pass phrase. On server side we have to enter the pass phrase while adding .pem file to server.

Answer (score 0):

To use your certificate on another server you should import your private key and install it on that server. If it won't be installed then second server couldn't use certificate that you are using to connect to APNS.

I think, you have forgotten to do this.

Comment: The other server is a windows system, where can i install primary key on that server. If you are talking about .pem file, he has placed it with php file on that server.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Boxed Ice's awesome guide](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/) which walks you through exporting your certificate and private key and getting it into a format that PHP can use to communicate with APNS. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Does your pem file contain private key as well?

Comment: Is other person able to connect to apns? It can be checked using following command  $ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert YourSSLCertAndPrivateKey.pem -debug -showcerts -CAfile server-ca-cert.pem  Looks like some kind of configuration related issue.

Comment: could you please elaborate what is the exact problem? what exact error he's receiving? Is connection to apns server using above command working at his end?